# How can I customize the soft keyboard for Amazon fire-tv?

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

I am building an commercial app for fire-tv, and I need to change the soft keyboard.  Add keys, resize the keyboard to fit screens etc. How can this be done on a fire-tv?

Comment: hey -1 lets chat out in the sun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are limited options for customizing the default on-screen keyboard.

When defining an `EditText` item, in XML you can use `android:inputType="number"` to switch to a numeric keyboard.

If you look at the `UIWidgetsSample` sample app in the Amazon Fire TV SDK there are some other options for customizing the on-screen keyboard (eg email) however for a large-scale customization you'll probably want to do as Hulu or Netflix have done and implement your own to have full control

Comment: I definitely need to do more.  So is it possible to implement a soft keyboard that is per app?  I know I can mimic it with a view, but when you say do as Hulu or Netflix and implement one's one, does that mean an actual soft keyboard that the user needs to install separately? or is it a keyboard mimic using just a view?  Or can a keyboard be packaged up with the app so its a real soft board, and the user does not need to install or uninstall it separately.  Thanks

Comment: in the Hulu/Netflix apps they look to be just something they are mimicking in a view. I don't know if the FireTV supports non-standard IME installation

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like custom view is the way to go.